# How can I update a row in Interbase database?

Tags: database, insert-update, interbase

I have two rows with same data in an Interbase table.The table does not have a primary key. How can I update a single row in that table?

Answer (score 0):

Interbase tables has a system column named RDB$DB_KEY. You can use that in the WHERE clause of your UPDATE query.

Comment: Hi I am trying to run an update query in interbase. But this is not working                                                              UPDATE ACSCHEDULE SET SCHNAME='SHARE' where rdb$db_key = '00800001'

Comment: AFAIK, db_key is a 8 byte integer and displayed as 16 character string. The sample you show is 8 characters. Are you sure using exact value you get from SELECT (including leftmost 0's)?

Comment: I am using Interbase 5.0 and when I select RDB$DB_KEY from my table its showing the same 8 characters only

Comment: Ok, try this: "UPDATE ACSCHEDULE SET SCHNAME='SHARE' WHERE ACSHEDULE.rdb$db_key = '00800001'", rdb$db_key must be qualified with table name even with one table selects or updates, see http://www.cvalde.net/document/mysteriousDbKeyIII.htm

Answer (score 0):

u can update those data directly to table (double click the table and search the data, update), not using SQL.